# Vertx Clustered EventBus not sending messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, hazelcast, vert.x, event-bus

[Diagram of Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAFd0.jpg)

I've setup TCP discovery using Hazelcast where parts of the cluster exist in and out of the AWS cloud.

Inside AWS I can send and receive messages no problem but not externally.

Looking at the members all 3 servers are in the list but no messages are sent to server 3 on my local machine.

For testing the AWS machines have their firewalls disabled, so the only thing I can think of is a firewall issue on my local network.

I tried making a new instance of Vertx on all servers setting the EventBus port to 80 but that stopped all messages.

Servers 1 or 2 are not reporting any failed to send issues, but I'm not sure what the problems is.

Anybody have any ideas as to why server 3 cannot send or receive messages despite being int he cluster?

Comment: As mentioned on our mailing list it is not recommended to put nodes into different environments (cloud+on-premise or 2 diff cloud providers), however it doesn't explain the behavior. Did you try any other communication between the members?

Comment: I only need one node to exist outside the cloud. I've been looking at the EventBus bridge. As I understand I will set-up a node which listens for requests on a set port and then translates them to the EventBus. Does Vert.x provide a client to create bridge messages easily? The bridge doesn't seem to support consume which is a big issue.

Comment: No idea if vertx can use Hazelcast clients but I would expect yes.